# Mute/unmute button for background sound

Tags: javascript, html, button, mute, background-music

guys. Please explain this to me.
I wanted to create a single mute/unmute button for my page. (audio starts automatically)
So here the code I used first time:

```js
<script>
var sound  = getElementById (‘background_sound’);
        function mute(){
          if(background_audio.muted == false){
            background_audio.muted = true;
          } else {
            background_audio.muted = false;
          }

}
</script>
```

But it didn’t work. So I just removed the first line (I mean this var) and addressed the id directly. And it worked. Now my html looks like this:

```html
<audio id="background_audio" autoplay="true" loop="loop">
          <source src="Audio/flute.mp3">
If you are reading this, it is because your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<button   onclick="mute()">
      <i class="fa fa-music"></i></button>
```

And javascript like this

```js
<script>

        function mute(){
          if(background_audio.muted == false){
            background_audio.muted = true;
          } else {
            background_audio.muted = false;
          }

}
</script>
```

The question is how can I address Id directly without creating a variable? It works fine though but will I have any problems with the code later? I just thought I need to assign a var this to work. A bit confused.

Comment: the `var sound = ..` line was quite badly formatted. Try instead `var background_audio = document.getElementById('background_sound');` and put it inside the `mute()` function.

Comment: Tried it. Still doesn't work this way. With var I mean. But without it works fine

Comment: sorry, it's `var background_audio = document.getElementById('background_audio');` there is no such a thing as `background_sound` in your html.

Answer (score 0):

try this i am sure this will work

```
 <script>

            function mute(){
              if(document.getElementById('background_audio').muted == false){
                document.getElementById('background_audio').muted = true;
              } else {
                document.getElementById('background_audio').muted = false;
              }

    }
    </script>
```